# MYSQL Select from table if it contains IPv6 networks included in a given IPv6 network

Tags: mysql, bitwise-operators, ipv6

I have a Mysql database (version 5.5.x without INET6_* functions) in which the addresses of the IPv6 networks VARBINARY(16) and prefixes TINYINT(3) are stored. When I add a new IPv6 network I would like to check if there are any child networks related to the new network.

Can it look something like this? For network 2001:4860:4860::8844/124:

```
SELECT HEX(ipv6), prefix FROM v6network 
WHERE ipv6 >= UNHEX('20014860486000000000000000008840') 
AND ipv6 <= UNHEX('2001486048600000000000000000884f')
```

or is it totaly wrong? Or can this be done with bitwise operators?

So my main questions are:

1. What kind of SELECT do I need to use for this?
2. And what would the SELECT look like if it were possible to use INET6_* functions?

Comment: You can use `IPv6 BETWEEN start AND end` instead of `ipv6 >= start AND ipv6 <= end`. But your code seems fine.

Comment: Does the query work for you or not?

Comment: In practice, your example really would not happen because you should really only use `/64` networks, except for point-to-point (`/127`) and loopbacks (`/128`). Other network sizes can break IPv6 features. Prefix lengths shorter than `/64` should represent multiple networks. Also, yes, IP addressing and subnetting for both IPv4 and IPv6 are done with bitwise operations, especially bitwise `AND` to mask an address to a network.

Comment: @Barmar it works for small tests, but I'm not sure about more complex conditions.

Comment: As long as you calculate the start/end values correctly, it should work for any prefix size.

Comment: Thank you @RonMaupin  Do you have any examples of SQL query for that?